# How to get random numbers in a table cell in html using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to generate number "1" in random cells from my table. There is a game like: you will select a table by pressing a button, after press play. When you will press play I want to put random the number "1" but not in all cells. (e.g: if table is 8x8, put 8 of "1" in the table, if table is 6x6, put 6 of "1" in the table and so on...) I create 3 tables in html and put them hidden with javascript.
Now I want some hints, some help from you guys. Thank you! Here is my code:

```js
//Variables
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
var button3 = document.getElementById('button3');
var backBtn = document.getElementById('back-btn');
var playBtn = document.getElementById('play-btn');
var sixTable = document.getElementById('sixXsix');
var eightTable = document.getElementById('eightXeight');
var steenTable = document.getElementById('steen');

//Visibility starter
sixTable.style.display = 'none';
eightTable.style.display = 'none';
steenTable.style.display = 'none';
backBtn.style.display = 'none';
playBtn.style.display = 'none';

//Buttons function
button1.onclick = function() {
  var six = document.getElementById('sixXsix');
  var eight = document.getElementById('eightXeight');
  var steen = document.getElementById('steen');

  if (six.style.display === 'none') {
    six.style.display = 'block';
    eight.style.display = 'none';
    steen.style.display = 'none';
    button1.style.display = 'none';
    button2.style.display = 'none';
    button3.style.display = 'none';
    backBtn.style.display = 'block';
    playBtn.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
button2.onclick = function() {
  var six = document.getElementById('sixXsix');
  var eight = document.getElementById('eightXeight');
  var steen = document.getElementById('steen');

  if (eight.style.display === 'none') {
    six.style.display = 'none';
    eight.style.display = 'block';
    steen.style.display = 'none';
    button1.style.display = 'none';
    button2.style.display = 'none';
    button3.style.display = 'none';
    backBtn.style.display = 'block';
    playBtn.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
button3.onclick = function() {
  var six = document.getElementById('sixXsix');
  var eight = document.getElementById('eightXeight');
  var steen = document.getElementById('steen');

  if (steen.style.display === 'none') {
    six.style.display = 'none';
    eight.style.display = 'none';
    steen.style.display = 'block';
    button1.style.display = 'none';
    button2.style.display = 'none';
    button3.style.display = 'none';
    backBtn.style.display = 'block';
    playBtn.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
backBtn.onclick = function() {
  sixTable.style.display = 'none';
  eightTable.style.display = 'none';
  steenTable.style.display = 'none';
  backBtn.style.display = 'none';
  playBtn.style.display = 'none';
  button1.style.display = 'block';
  button2.style.display = 'block';
  button3.style.display = 'block';

}

playBtn.onclick = function() {

}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="button1">6x6 Table</button>
  <button id="button2">8x8 Table</button>
  <button id="button3">16x16 Table</button>
  <button id="back-btn">Back</button>
  <button id="play-btn">Play</button>
</div>
<div id="table">
  <div id="sixXsix">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="eightXeight">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="steen">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a **minimal and verifiable** sample and not your entire code

Comment: You could start by googling or searching SO on random javascript

Comment: Also a working sample would be nice as well. This code gives an immediate error `Cannot read property 'style' of null"`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I fixed that. The HTML was outside the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code uses jquery to generate random numbers between 1 and the number of cells and then places a 1 in the corresponding cell.

If any of it is not clear, let me know.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#playBtn').on('click', function() {
  var cellsCount = $('#table1 td').length;
  var rows = $('#table1 tr').length;
  var usedCells = [];

  if (rows != $("#table1 tr:first-child td").length) {
    alert("The grid is not a square, I dont know how many cells to mark.");
    return;
  }

  // empty all cells first
  $("#table1 td").empty();
  $("#table1 td").css("background-color", "white");

  // generate random numbers between 1 and the number of cells available
  // (no duplicates)
  while (usedCells.length < rows) {
    randCell = Math.floor(Math.random() * cellsCount);
    if (usedCells.indexOf(randCell) == -1) {
      usedCells.push(randCell);
    }
  }
  // for each number generate, color the cell and add the "1"
  $.each(usedCells, function(index, value) {
    cell = "#table1 td:eq(" + value + ")";
    $(cell).html("1");
    $(cell).css("background-color", "red");
  });

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="playBtn">Play</button>
<br>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet uses a templating method (`interpolate`) to create a nXn table containing n random cells with value 1. See [this git-repo](https://github.com/KooiInc/PureHelpers#interpolate) for usage of `interpolate`.

```js
(function () {
  
  String.prototype.interpolate = function (tokens) { 
    return interpolate(this, tokens); 
  };
  document.querySelector("#buttons")
    .addEventListener('click', createTable);
    
  document.querySelector("#button1").click();
    
  function createTable(evt) {
    const origin = evt.target;
    if ( !/button/i.test(origin.nodeName)) { return; }
    const size = origin.getAttribute('data-table')
      .split('x')
      .reduce(function (a, b, i) { 
          i == 1 ? a.rows = +b : a.cols = +b; return a;
        }, {} );
    size.totalCells = size.rows * size.cols;
    const fillCells = getUniqueRandomValues(size.cols, size.totalCells);      
    let cellCount = 0;
    const rowCells = () => '<td{hasValue}>&nbsp;</td>'
       .interpolate( Array(size.rows).join(",").split(",")
           .map( () => { 
               return { 
                hasValue: fillCells.indexOf(cellCount++) > -1 
                  ? " class=\"hasValue\"" 
                  : ""
               };
            }
           )
    );
    const rows = '<tr>{cell}</tr>'.interpolate( 
         Array(size.rows).join(",").split(",")
             .map( () => { return { cell: rowCells() }; } )
    );
    const header = ('<tr><td colspan="{colsize}" class="header">' +
                    '{rowsize} rows, {colsize} columns</td><tr>')
                   .interpolate({colsize: size.cols, rowsize: size.rows});
    
    document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML =  
      '<table>{rows}</table>'
        .interpolate( { rows: header + rows });
  }
  
  function getUniqueRandomValues(nValues, maxRandomValue) {
      let existing = {};
      maxRandomValue -= 1;
      const randomUnique = () => {
          const rndm = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * maxRandomValue);
          const exists = existing[rndm];
          if ( !exists ) { existing[rndm] = 1; }
          return exists ? randomUnique() : rndm;
        };
      return Array(nValues).join(",").split(",")
        .map( () => randomUnique() ) ;
  }
  
  function interpolate(string2Interpolate, tokens) {
    if (!(tokens instanceof Array) && tokens instanceof Object) {
        tokens = [tokens];
    } else if (!(tokens instanceof Object)) {
        return string2Interpolate;
    }
    let replacer = function (token) {
      return function (t, t1, t2) { 
        return token[t2] === '' 
          ? String.fromCharCode(0)
          : token[t2] || t; 
      };
    }
    let str = string2Interpolate;
    return tokens.map(function (token) {
        return str.replace(/(\{?)([a-z_0-9]+)(\})/gi, replacer(token));
    }).join('').replace(RegExp(String.fromCharCode(0), "g"), '');
  }
}());
```

```css
body { font: 12px verdana, arial; }
table { margin-top: 1em; }
table td {
  text-align: right; 
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0; 
  padding: 2px;
  min-width: 1.2em;
  min-height: 1.2em;}
table td.header {
  background-color: black; 
  color: white; 
  text-align: center; 
}
td.hasValue {
  background-color: green; 
  color: white;
}
td.hasValue:before {
  content: "1";
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="button1" data-table="6x6">
    6x6 Table
  </button>
  <button id="button2" data-table="8x8">
    8x8 Table
  </button>
  <button id="button3" data-table="16x16">
    16x16 Table
  </button>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```